# Custom UITableViewCell reverts to standard blue cell for selectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a **subclass** of `UITableViewCell` that gives me custom styling and extra data.

All works well when the user interacts, however when I programmatically select it by calling `selectRowAtIndexPath` it reverts back to the standard selected `UITableViewCell` with blue background.

Here is my code

```
[myTable selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

Answer (score 1):

See this question: [UITableView Cell selected Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998775/uitableview-cell-selected-color)

As a workaround, you can override `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and set background color there:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
```

To set `backgroungColor` to normal color override `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Just trying this now, but it's not removing that background color when it's deselected.

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, then after calling :

```
[myTable selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

add this line:

```
[[myTable delegate]tableView:myTable selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
```

write:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Comment: I have done that already but it has no effect on the selected style

Comment: That's removed all styling

Comment: if you have done some custom styling of yourself, it should override default

Comment: @PaulMrG just use `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;`. Don't set selectedBackground to nil. Now what happens?

Comment: Don't know which method you mean to put it in so tried both cellForRowAtIndexPath and didSelectRowAtIndexPath (separately) and either one is removing all styling.

Comment: look at this. I think this is what you need... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425265/how-to-add-a-custom-cell-on-select-event-of-uitableview-in-accordion-style

Answer (score 0):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method add this line before returning your cell instance:

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

Comment: Same as what I've tried from @anum90 it removes all styling instead of using my custom styling

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the workaround as suggested by @Andrey Gordeev I extended that to include removing the style layer once the cell is deselected.

*I still need to use my custom cell for other reasons, but I have shown it as a standard cell below so anyone can use it*

To apply your own style if you have to call

```
[myTable selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

To add a gradient layer when **selecting** a cell

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    [gradient setFrame:[cell.contentView bounds]];
    [gradient setColors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.70 alpha:1.0] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.50 alpha:1.0] CGColor], nil]];
    [[cell.contentView layer] insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
    // The next line makes a reference to the gradient layer for selection and removal later on
    [[cell.contentView layer] setValue:gradient forKey:@"GradientLayer"];

    ...

}
```

To remove the gradient layer when **deselecting** a cell

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Get the layer using the reference to it
    CALayer *gradientLayer = [[cell.contentView layer] valueForKey:@"GradientLayer"];
    [gradientLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
    [[cell.contentView layer] setValue:nil forKey:@"GradientLayer"];

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, here is how I solved it :

In `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

`UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CELL_NAME];...`

```
      // Cell custom style
UIImage *background             = [self cellBackgroundForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImageView *cellBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:background];
cellBackgroundView.image        = background;
cell.backgroundView             = cellBackgroundView;

UIImage *selectedBackground             = [self cellBackgroundForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImageView *cellselectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:background];
cellBackgroundView.image                = selectedBackground;
cell.selectedBackgroundView             = cellselectedBackgroundView;
```